# HTML and JS basics, filling form after clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to calculate the time it takes light to travel a given number of kilometers in a vacuum.
I have the form with some inputs and submit button and I want the calculated time in JS script and display results in the Result [min] and Result [h] fields in the form, after clicking the submit button, but it isn't working. What can be wrong here?

This is my form:

```
<div class="text-justify index_text_style">
    <p>This is a calculator that allows you to calculate the time it takes light to travel a given number of kilometers in a vacuum.</p>
</div>
<form class="light_forms">
    <label class="index_text_style" for="km_count">Enter number</label>
    <input type="number" id="km_count" name="km_count">
         <label class="index_text_style" for="km_count">[km]</label>
         <br> <br>

         <label class="index_text_style" for="result_min">Result: </label>
         <input type="text" id="result_min" name="result_min" disabled>
         <label class="index_text_style" for="result_min">[min] </label>
         <br> <br>

         <label class="index_text_style" for="result_h">Result: </label>
         <input type="text" id="result_h" name="result_h" disabled>
         <label class="index_text_style" for="result_h">[h] </label>
         <br> <br>

         <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="results()"> <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

and my scrpit placed just before body closing tag:

```
            <script>

                function results(){
                var km_count = document.getElementByID("km_count").value;
                var result_1 = km_count / 300 000 / 60;
                var result_2 = km_count / 300 000 / 3600;

                document.getElementById("result_min").innerHTML = result_1;
                document.getElementById("result_h").innerHTML = result_2;
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: `300 000` ??? You mean `300000` or more readable `300_000`

Comment: Yes, you right, I changed it, but something's still wrong

Comment: Stop using inline `on*` handlers. Use addEventListener() instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the following problems in your code:

- Using `document.getElementByID` instead of `document.getElementById`
  (typo)
- Using the `click` event handler on your submit button instead of the
  `submit` event on the form (more appropriate)
- Not using `event.preventDefault()` in your event handler, so that the
  browser won't propagate the event and won't fulfill its part of the
  game actually performing a new http request
- You were setting the inputs content with `.innerHTML` instead of
  using the more appropriate in this case `.value` like you already did
  with the input

In addition to that, as already suggested by some other comments, it would be more appropriate to add the event handler using `.addEventListener` instead of dealing with the `on`*eventname* attribute on html doing the binding in another realm.

In this snippet below I also kept the logic to calculate the distance traveled in a separate function `getTimeSpent(km, speed)` that will be general, relative to the speed that now it's required to be passed from the caller.

Since the speed parameter was generalized, I put it inside the `data-speed` attribute of the input element for the distance (km). Anyway if it won't be set, the `lightspeed` value (defined apart as a constant in the global scope) will be used.

The caller is just a mere event handler with the knowledge of the html elements for input and output and of the function to calculate the distance traveled.

The maths for calculating the distance was better factored to avoid the repeating of the same operation multiple times.

```js
document.querySelector('form.light_forms')
  .addEventListener('submit', event => {
    const inputKM = document.getElementById("km_count");
    const distanceKM = parseFloat(inputKM.value);
    
    //the speed gets fetched from the data-speed attribute if it's present,
    //otherwise it's the constant lightspeed set in the higher scope
    const speedKMperS =
      (inputKM.hasAttribute("data-speed")) ?
        parseFloat(inputKM.dataset.speed) : lightspeed;
    
    const time = getTimeSpent(distanceKM, speedKMperS);
    
    document.getElementById("result_min").value = time.minutes;
    document.getElementById("result_h").value = time.hours;
    
    event.preventDefault();
  });

const lightspeed = 300000;

function getTimeSpent(km, speed) {

  const seconds = km / speed;
  const minutes =  seconds / 60;
  const hours = minutes / 60;

  return {
    hours: hours,
    minutes: minutes,
    seconds: seconds
  };
}
```

```html
<div class="text-justify index_text_style">
  <p>This is a calculator that allows you to calculate the time it takes light to travel a given number of kilometers in a vacuum.</p>
</div>

<form class="light_forms">
  <label class="index_text_style" for="km_count">Enter number</label>
  <input type="number" id="km_count" name="km_count" data-speed="300000">
  <label class="index_text_style" for="km_count">[km]</label>
  <br><br>

  <label class="index_text_style" for="result_min">Result: </label>
  <input type="text" id="result_min" name="result_min" disabled>
  <label class="index_text_style" for="result_min">[min] </label>
  <br><br>

  <label class="index_text_style" for="result_h">Result: </label>
  <input type="text" id="result_h" name="result_h" disabled>
  <label class="index_text_style" for="result_h">[h] </label>
  <br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="results()">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did it in my own way, but used your advices.
The main problem was with the reloading the page after "submit" and using .innerHTML instead of .value. The other comments were also very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a "**submit**" button each click/submit will reload the page, in your case, you need to prevent default behavior (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Also, I recommend you to use addEventlistner (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

here is a quick fix for your code:

```
<form class="light_forms" onsubmit="return results(event)">
    <label class="index_text_style" for="km_count">Enter number</label>
    <input type="number" id="km_count" name="km_count">
     <label class="index_text_style" for="km_count">[km]</label>
     <br> <br>

     <label class="index_text_style" for="result_min">Result: </label>
     <input type="text" id="result_min" name="result_min" disabled>
     <label class="index_text_style" for="result_min">[min] </label>
     <br> <br>

     <label class="index_text_style" for="result_h">Result: </label>
     <input type="text" id="result_h" name="result_h" disabled>
     <label class="index_text_style" for="result_h">[h] </label>
     <br> <br>

     <input type="submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

<script>

    function results(event){
       event.preventDefault();
        var km_count = document.getElementById("km_count").value;
        var result_1 = km_count / 300000 / 60;
        var result_2 = km_count / 300000 / 3600;

        document.getElementById("result_min").value  = result_1;
        document.getElementById("result_h").value  = result_2;
    }
</script>
```